# iOS SBJsonWriter returns null

Tags: objective-c, ios, null, sbjson

I´m using the SBJson framework the first time, and I´ve got a big problem, the following code always returns null. The NSDictionary is correctly filled (I printed every value out!).

```
NSDictionary *nsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSString *jsonString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:nsDictionary];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

I also tried this:

```
NSDictionary *nsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [SBJsonWriter new];
NSString *jsonString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:nsDictionary];
NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

Comment: Have you validated that the JSON you're parsing is valid? Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate, also consider using http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html instead of SBJSONParser

Comment: I can´t use apple´s framework because my app must be compatible with iOS 4.X >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary may contains objects that cannot be written by `SBJsonWriter`.

You may use `-[SBJsonWriter stringWithObject:error:]` to get the failure's reason.

```
NSDictionary *nsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [SBJsonWriter new];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *jsonString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:nsDictionary error:&error];
if ( ! jsonString ) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, SBJsonWriter can't handle NSDate

Comment: Converting an NSDate to a double is a good fix for JSON format: @([date timeIntervalSince1970])